# Jquery/Colourbox many links to colourbox galleries/Array?

Tags: jquery, gallery, hyperlink, colorbox

Thanks Christopher for 
[jQuery / Colorbox - create a separate link to open the colorbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937520/jquery-colorbox-create-a-separate-link-to-open-the-colorbox)
I need more than one link, how can I coding it more elegant way than now
i will have nine galleries..An Array?
http://carlossilva.org/test_colorbox.html

Thank everybody for taking time!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that. Here is a simple one that dynamically forms the REL attribute. You could get much more elegant than this with a few more minutes...

**HTML**

```
<body>
<ul>
    <li id="gal0">Gallery 1</a>
    <li id="gal1">Gallery 2</a>
</ul>

<div class="cannotview">
    <a href="img/tour1.jpg" rel="gal0"></a>
    <a href="img/tour2.jpg" rel="gal0"></a>
    <a href="img/tour3.jpg" rel="gal1"></a>
    <a href="img/tour4.jpg" rel="gal1"></a>
</div>

</body>
```

**JQuery**

```
$().ready(function () { 
   $('li').one('click', function () { 
        var myRel ='a[rel=' + $(this).attr("id") + ']';
        var $gallery = $(myRel).colorbox().eq(0);
        $gallery.click(); 

        $(this).click(function(){
            $gallery.click();
        });
    });
});
```

Regards, Kevin M.

Comment: Thanks, Jack.  I'd love to compare my incorrect take to yours but don't know how to do that on StackOverflow... :(

Comment: next problem : How can i highlight the li (like a:hover or cursor to show that they are clickable?? best Regards, nastia