# Specify URL in jquery link

Tags: jquery, colorbox

how can I call colorbox and the URL from a jquery link?

I have this:

```
$(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
```

And then I have this:

```
onclick=""
```

And I would like to be able to specify the address in the `onclick=""` function.

Sorry, I tried to shorten my question so there isn't a wall of text:

I want to change this link:

```
<a class='iframe' href="www.google.com"></a>
```

To a Jquery one.

Most solutions I've looked up have done this:

```
onClick="lightbox()"


$.fn.colorbox({width:"80%", height:"80%", iframe:true, href:"www.google.com"});
```

However that would require me to create a colorbox function for each address, and I have lot's of them. Thanks for understanding :)

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Perhaps you're after [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937520/jquery-colorbox-create-a-separate-link-to-open-the-colorbox)?

Comment: We're missing a bit of context here. What is the element with class ".iframe" (and iframe ?) ? Is the onclick to be applied on ".iframe" as well ?

Comment: Sorry, I added a little more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, I just realized that the current version of colorbox doesn't work with jQuery 1.6.3, and I can't seem to find a download link for older versions. Thanks anyways everyone!

Comment: whats the reason you cant upgrade jquery? and colorbox website says it works with jquery 1.3+ ?

Comment: I'm using other plugins that seem to have problems with newer jQuery... Specifically jScrollPane

Answer (score 1):

would something like this work? if you can use functions inside a paramater?

```
$(".iframe").colorbox({
    iframe: true,
    width: "80%",
    height: "80%",
    href: function() {
          var location = $(this).attr('href');
          return location;
          }
});
```

this will set the href to what ever has been clicked, you can change the attr href to a different attribute like, rel or anything but you cant use onclick. If you do use href then you might need to use a e.PreventDefault in the click event otherwise it will still try load that href as normal.

Comment: Hmm, thank you! I checked the event.preventDefault() documentation, however I'm still confused how I would do the click function, since you said I cannot use onclick :/.

The reason why I used onclick is because the colorbox modal will open when a user clicks a table row. Such as this:
`<tr onclick="alert('Bob Squarepants')">`